# Has SRAM discontinued i-light hub dynamo?

Tags: hub, sram, dynamo

I haven't been able to find SRAM hub dynamos lately. Has SRAM discontinued making of hub dynamos?

Comment: http://www.bike-eu.com/sales-trends/nieuws/2017/2/sram-stops-remaining-internal-gear-hub-production-10129065 blames them discontinuing their hub gear range on electric bikes taking much of their market. I imagine that's true of dynamos as well - no point using a battery to power a motor to drive a wheel with a dynamo. But I don't know for sure, so not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [page](http://www.treefortbikes.com/product/333222358468/1464/SRAM-i-Light-Dynamo-730.html) yes, the hub

> is discontinued and is no longer available

[image]

@armb's assumption may be true. They stopped making IGH's and dynamo hubs for the same reason, at the same time. I-light had such a small market share that it didn't even earned to be mentioned.